# Sql query group by(Get count using where condition)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Stuck in group by clause.

```
Col1      Col2
----------------
1         1
1         2
2         1
3         3
4         2
5         4
2         3
```

I want count of Col2 such that Col2 value is 1:
The output expected is:

```
Col1      Count(Col2)
---------------------
1         1
2         1
3         0
4         0
5         0
```

Comment: Please show the query you are using... Also what DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using sql server.

Answer (score 0):

```
;with
d as (
select * from (values 
(1,         1),
(1,         2),
(2,         1),
(3,         3),
(4,         2),
(5,         4),
(2,         3)) x (Col1, Col2)
)
select distinct d1.Col1, isnull(cnt, 0) cnt
from d d1
left join (
    select Col1, COUNT(Col2) cnt
    from d d1
    where Col2=1
    group by Col1, col2
) d2 on d1.Col1 = d2.Col1 
order by 1,2
```

Output:

```
Col1    Cnt
1       1
2       1
3       0
4       0
5       0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select col1, sum(case when col2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
from t
group by col1;
```